# Accessing Ranges of Data in Vectorized Way MATLAB

Tags: matlab, vectorization

I have a column vector of data in variable `vdata` and a list of indeces `idx`. I want to access `vdata` at the indeces `x` before and `x` after each index in `idx`. One way I would do it in a for loop is:

```
x = 10;
accessed_data = [];
for (ii = 1:length(idx))
    accessed_data = vdata(idx-x:idx+x);
end
```

Is there a way to do this in a vectorized function? I found a solution to a very similar question here: [Addressing multiple ranges via indices in a vector](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13688345/addressing-multiple-ranges-via-indices-in-a-vector) but I don't understand the code :(.

Comment: What result do you want exactly? A matrix with one row for each `ii`?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Assuming `min(idx)-x>0` and `max(idx)+x<=numel(vdata)` then you can simply do

```
 iidx = bsxfun(@plus, idx(:), -x:x); % create all indices
 accessed_data = vdata( iidx );
```

Comment: When did they start allowing you to apply `bsxfun` to two transposed vectors? I always remember having to build a matrix first so that the non-singleton dimensions of the two input arrays would match each other? But now I see this works in R2012b. Am I confused?

Comment: @horchler AFAIK it has always been this way. see [tag:bsxfun] tag wiki for more examples (feel welcome to contribute).

Comment: The [doc for `bsxfun`](http://www.mathworks.com/help/releases/R2007a/techdoc/index.html?/help/releases/R2007a/techdoc/ref/bsxfun.html) from R2007a (the function's debut) seems to back you up. I don't know were I picked up that idea.

Comment: `BSXFUN` was spot on. I had never heard of this function before but this is exactly what I needed. Thanks Shai and horchler!

Comment: @navr91 `bsxfun` is a GREAT function. visit its [tag:bsxfun] wiki

Answer (score 2):

One scheme that uses direct indexing instead of a `for` loop:

```
xx = (-x:x).';                            % Range of indices
idxx = bsxfun(@plus,xx(:,ones(1,numel(idx))),idx(:).'); % Build array
idxx = idxx(:);                           % Columnize to interleave columns
idxx = idxx(idxx>=1&idxx<=length(vdata)); % Make sure the idx+/-x is valid index
accessed_data = vdata(idxx);              % Indices of data
```

The second line can be replaced with a form of the first line from @Shai's answer. This scheme checks that all of the resultant indices are valid. Because some might have to be removed, you could end up with a ragged array. One way to solve this is to use cell arrays, but here I just make `idxx` a vector, and thus `accessed_data` is as well.

Answer (score 0):

This gives the solution in a matrix, with one row for each value in `idx`. It assumes that all values in `idx` are greater than or equal to `x`, and less than or equal to `length(vdata)-x`.

```
% Data
x = 10;
idx = [12 20 15];
vdata = 1:100;

ind = repmat(-x:x,length(idx),1) + repmat(idx(:),1,2*x+1);
vdata(ind)
```

Comment: Sheer ignorance, I'm afraid. Is `bsxfun` faster?

Comment: check out the [tag:bsxfun] tag wiki for more info

Comment: @Shai: In the old days `repmat` was not implemented as a native function and it was definitely true that it could be slow. Less so now (I'm not sure which version this happened in). Also, on my own hardware, I've seen that `bsxfun` is actually slower than replicating methods for sufficiently small arrays. Not sure why (memory allocation speed vs. CPU speed?). However, if one is to optimize for the worst case, then `bsxfun` is way to go.